# Official policy on questions posted as answers

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

In regards to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c/573342#573342) (but I have seen it quite often), what is the official policy (or the common practice) for what to do when someone posts a question as an answer to another question? I've seen this happen quite a few times, and I just flag it as "Needs Moderator Attention" but I feel bad putting any more work on moderators, I don't even know if it's worth their attention, and I don't even know what to do? Should we comment and tell them not to post questions as answers? Should we downvote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flag it for moderator attention and we will delete it.

Comment: Glad to know I've been doing it right.

Answer (score 1):

IMO I would comment on the question and tell him to ask it as a question and link to the original one.

I wouldn't downvote though.

Comment: I wouldn't downvote either, but downvotes seem to happen to these a lot. The problem is that if this is a new user who never comes back, their garbage doesn't get cleaned up, so their question-answer stays there. Or is it not worth worrying about?