# I shouldn't be down-voted as much as I am, or by the people that are, and also punishments should abound for askers who fail to accept an answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Weighted Down-Voting based on Reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54494/weighted-down-voting-based-on-reputation)
>   [Encourage users to select ‘Accepted Answer’ for old Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10672/encourage-users-to-select-accepted-answer-for-old-questions)
>   [Force Accepted Answers on Questions by Inactive Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8692/force-accepted-answers-on-questions-by-inactive-users)
>   [Should questions with no accepted answers be charged “interest” after awhile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23475/should-questions-with-no-accepted-answers-be-charged-interest-after-awhile)
>   [Max downvotes per question/answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24826/max-downvotes-per-question-answer)
>   [Downvotes appear to be pure evil](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31842/downvotes-appear-to-be-pure-evil)
>   [Upvoting based on celebrity, too many upvotes (“excessive rep slurping”)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/upvoting-based-on-celebrity-too-many-upvotes-excessive-rep-slurping)
>   [Are we too rep-focused?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5329/are-we-too-rep-focused)
>   [Vote to delete answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17296/vote-to-delete-answers)
>   [Reedem reputation for deleted negative answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/reedem-reputation-for-deleted-negative-answers)

1. I hate it how I have absolutely zero chance of getting reputation back when someone downvotes me, even when I'm obviously right. People downvote because they are stupid (sorry, but it happens) or because they didn't understand my answer, and after I clarifiy, they are long gone or don't care anymore/enough. People also downvote impulsively or because others downvoted. I think that after one downvote, more downvotes shouldnt be allowed for a certain period of time unless the downvote comes from someone who has more rep than the person before.
2. I also don't like that there is no guide on posting or strict enforcement of such.
   If someone poses a question in the "Add another answer" dialogue, then this must clearly be wrong behaviour. Still they get away with it.

   This is clearly a site that puts the wrong focus on the people, instead of the quality of the answers. Someone who has more rep, should count more when up or downvoting, and someone who downvotes very often, has little rep or accepts answers very rarely shouldn't be able to deteriorate my rep.
3. It should also be punished if someone doesn't accept an answer, or at least make it auto accept the answer which has the most rep.

Comment: Wouldn't giving people with higher rep more weight in voting be putting focus on the people instead of the answer?

Comment: Yes, the right people and therefore the answers. As you know, people post answers.

Comment: Duplicate of [Weighted Down-Voting based on Reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54494/how-can-i-ensure-the-right-sort-of-people-are-voting-on-my-answers)

Comment: No, at best it's partly a duplicate. And since I only have 1 rep to begin with, your downvotes bounce off me nicely :)

Comment: @Blub: yeah, I suspect you should have split this into several posts... #3 is probably a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8692/force-accepted-answers-on-questions-by-inactive-users and similar to quite a few [other suggestions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10672/encourage-users-to-select-accepted-answer-for-old-questions) as well.

Comment: @Blub, it seems to me that you have a specific example or two in mind; could you please link to them?

Comment: @Blub: You show demonstratively, that you haven't understood the voting system at all. *Posts* are voted on, not people. Content matters. People suck.

Comment: Regarding #2, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25752/official-policy-on-questions-posted-as-answers

Comment: I agree with all of your points besides 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: Yes here is an example where I didnt get accepted as answer:
(please realize that this is a hobby for me. I do not leave this site just because I get downvoted. I voice my honest dislike of the system nevertheless)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319082/how-to-develop-add-in-extensions-for-visual-studio-2010-source-reference/3319140#3319140

My answer got downvoted even though it was in many ways better and more to the core of the problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236638/adding-values-to-float-array-contents-still-equal-to-0-0/3236860#3236860

Comment: @Ladybug: People do not care what matters to the system. They still get offended or proud.

Comment: @Blub: So stop being so offended by downvotes and being too proud of your answers. Problem solved.

Comment: @Weblog: I wasn't necessarily talking about myself, and if you knew people, you would know that problems dont get solved by saying "just stop feeling that way and ur fine."

Comment: @Blub: It doesn't work only because you're too proud of the way you're doing things, which you admit is a problem. So be less proud and accept that your way might be wrong, that being proud and offended by trivial things is wrong. The first step toward improvement is recognizing the problem.

Comment: @Blub: regarding your first example... I've had to wait *months* for an accepted answer. I've posted answers that have *never* been accepted, in spite of comments from the asker that they've been successful in utilizing it. It's an optional action, you can't force it.

Comment: @Weblog: Well, I'm not prepared to accept that I'm wrong just because I'm the minority with my opinion. Arguments count!

Comment: @Blub: That is fair. However it doesn't make you right, either. SO has been operating for over a year with only a tiny minority of its users like you complaining about its functionality from a reward/punishment point of view. Scientifically, the theories governing SO are right more often than they're wrong. That is good enough for any community, especially one with community moderation built right into it. Unless, of course, you have evidence that the system isn't actually working as intended on a large scale. I don't think you have such evidence.

Comment: @Blub : I think you might benefit from a read of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying , many of it's concepts are applicable to StackOverflow as well.

Comment: @Blub Regarding your suggestions, the things that you mention are **not arbitrary**, and they have been planned, talked about, experimented with, discussed, and voted on. You **are** entitled to your opinion, but please understand that things are the way they are for good reason (and what those reasons are, see earlier links).

Comment: I have a feeling this post had something to do with me receiving yet another downvote on one of my answers from way back that I had a bit of a moan about.  Ahh, the joys of meta... :-) I learned here that the worst thing you can do about downvotes is complain!

Comment: @Blub - if you are responding to a comment, especially made by someone who cast a down vote on your answer, use @user when replying. This alerts them that you have replied to them the next time they load a page. Otherwise, they usually have no idea that you posted any kind of clarification. I think the answer in question is this one (?): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236638/why-isnt-my-index-variable-increasing-when-i-add-numbers-to-it/3236860#3236860

Comment: I read recently that people don't downvote enough, and when they do the post just gets sympathy upvotes. Huh. Strange world we live in.

Comment: @Tim Post: Thanks that was helpful already, but what exactly do you mean with @user? Does it have to be the full name? Some names are really long to write. Well, these little bits of information are really hard to come by. For example: Why can I not upvote anymore suddenly? Should I ask this kind of question here on meta? Those are really small. Like: Where do I find the user wiki everybody is mentioning so often?

Comment: @Blub , if I'm not mistaken, you need only the first (four ?) characters and it will address the 'first match' .. if in doubt, just copy / paste :)

Comment: @Tim: the first three.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I hate it how I have absolutely zero chance of getting reputation back...

Delete your answer and request a reputation recalc using the "flag for moderator attention."  You'll get your rep back.

> ...even when I'm obviously right.

Must not have been so obvious.

> ...or because they didn't understand my answer...

If they didn't understand your answer, then it probably belongs in the "not helpful" category, which is what a downvote means.  Don't take it personally, just try to clarify your answer as best you can.  If your answer is helpful then the next person to read it will upvote it.

> I think that after one downvote, more downvotes shouldnt be allowed for a certain period of time unless the downvote comes from someone who has more rep than the person before.

No, we've been over this before.  I have a lot of reputation from answering questions about Java, but I know nothing about a *lot* of other languages.  My vote shouldn't count for more than yours over a very wide range of topics.

> If someone poses a question in the "Add another answer" dialogue, then this must clearly be wrong behaviour. Still they get away with it.

Please flag these "answers" for moderator attention.  I delete a lot of these every day, so they're not really getting away with it.

> This is clearly a site that puts the wrong focus on the people, instead of the quality of the answers. Someone who has more rep, should count more when up or downvoting, and someone who downvotes very often, has little rep or accepts answers very rarely shouldn't be able to deteriorate my rep.

You seem to be contradicting yourself here.  The focus *should* be on the quality of the content, not the person.  If you take overall rep into account, you'd be focusing more on the person casting the votes.

> It should also be punished if someone doesn't accept an answer, or at least make it auto accept the answer which has the most rep.

No, that's voluntary.  It's a *bonus* if your answer gets accepted, not a mandatory requirement.  If you give the right answer, then you should gain plenty of rep in the form of upvotes and your answer will rise to the top of the page.

Comment: I admire your commitment, @Bill.

Comment: @Bill: citation: Please flag these "answers" for moderator attention. I delete a lot of these every day, so they're not really getting away with it.

What about punishment? This shouldn't sound cruel, but humans (as I am) generally do not alter their behaviour when they get corrected unless it has consequences.

Comment: @Ladybug Killer: Thank you, I appreciate your saying so.

Comment: @Blub: There are generally three ways to get people to change their behavior: Education, punishment, and reward.  You don't need to try punishment or reward until you give education a try.  The *vast* majority of questions posted as answers are by users with one reputation.  They just need to be told how the system works.  They get rewarded when they ask a question properly and it actually gets answers.  There's usually no need to punish them.

Comment: @bill: In what way do they get educated when you moderate a question? Well I just had one guy be really condescending to me with a lot more rep than me. I guess I really like stackoverflow, it's just sad to me that I can't get the same kind of reward as I give others when they answer my questions.

Comment: @Blub: If it's a brand new user, I leave a comment telling them they should ask a separate question and point them to the **[Ask Question]** button.  One thing you can try is to check a user's accept rate before you answer their question.  (It's posted below their reputation and badges in the question body.)  If they have a really low accept-rate, you're less likely to get an upvote or an accepted answer from them.

Answer (score 3):

I'll try to hit all the salient points of your rant:

- Most of your criticisms are mitigated by the fact that an upvote is 5 times the weight of a downvote with respect to Rep earned, so in the long run downvotes mean very little.
- With respect to this statement you made:

  > This is clearly a site that puts the
  >   wrong focus on the people, instead of
  >   the quality of the answers.

  Who is there to determine the quality, if not the *people*? The *people* are needed to help separate the wheat from the chaff via their votes. Arguably, downvotes probably aren't used *enough* in this regard.

  It has been said many times that Rep is not necessarily a measure of *skill*, simply a measure of ones involvement in the site. So, weighting votes by Rep is pointless, since higher Rep users are not necessarily *experts*.
- An accepted answer is also only 1.5 times the weight of an upvote, so if people don't accept an answer you're not losing much Rep relative to the upvotes you likely got for the answer. Also, the votes from the community are enough to show which answer is best.

Comment: Ok, you answered a single thing of my 10 billion criticism post. Hope to hear more.

Comment: I would say that all 4 of his bullet points directly relate to your question.

Comment: @Neil N: I've been editing in more points as I go. He had a lot of them. ;)